# How to make path into an SQLite database directory dynamic for multiple directories?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, cd

Hi everyone and thank you for your time. Sorry, I'm not fully sure if I'm explaining this properly, but feel free to ask any further question to get further insight into my problem.

I have a Python script that connects to an SQLite db directory like so:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\gareth\Desktop\pastRuns\test_cpd49-1.70.101.iso\test_cpd49-1.70.101.iso.db');
```

In the directory /pastRuns, I have multiple directories with similar names to test_cpd49-1.70.101.iso which also have corresponding .db files inside them. Example below:

```
  /pastRuns 
      /test_cpd49-1.70.101.iso
         -->test_cpd49-1.70.101.iso.db
      /test_cpd49-1.70.119.iso
         -->test_cpd49-1.70.119.iso.db
      /test_cpd49-1.70.127.iso
         -->test_cpd49-1.70.127.iso.db
      /test_cpd49-1.71.104.iso
         -->test_cpd49-1.71.104.iso.db
      /test_cpd49-1.72.166.iso
         -->test_cpd49-1.72.166.iso.db
```

Is it possible to make that path to each of the `.db` files dynamic so that I don't have to have multiple entry points?

Comment: try os.walk and join the path with - os.path.join

Comment: Can you show an example of how you imagine that working? Perhaps describe a use-case? It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve at this level.

Comment: There exists both a .db and .json file in the .iso folder. When the .json file is updated, I have to compare the new data against what's in the .db file and update the .db file, if new data exists in the .json file. I have most of the logic for that part done. I just want try try automate this process and loop through all of the .iso files and perform the same task. But i'm trying to find a work around the static db connection address, if that's possible. I hope this gives you a better idea of what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but you try something like this to get the path of the db files and then connect to them

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\gareth\Desktop\pastRuns'

for f in os.walk(path):
    if f[2] and f[2][0].endswith('.db'):
        print(os.path.join(f[0],f[2][0]))
        conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(f[0],f[2][0]))
        # program logic goes here
        conn.close()
```

Comment: This connects to all the databases and then discards the connection objects without closing them. It's unlikely that this is what OP wants.